# How to remove multiple text strings from a cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say the cell A1 contains:

```
Some fog eh Pop I've already heard the weather report Drive please Boy It's as thick as pea soup Not a soul around for miles Know what I think pop Perfect place for a murder Conversation like television set on honeymoon Unnecessary
```

And I want to remove the words `the`, `I`, `It's`, `as`, `a`, `for`, and `on` from it.

It seems the `REGEXREPLACE` or `SUBSTITUTE` function should be used:

```
SUBSTITUTE(text_to_search, search_for, replace_with, [occurrence_number])
```

Is there a way to insert multiple values in the search_for parameter? I can't find any documentation on this...

Comment: So I appear to be making progress, but hitting a snag.  
  
I'm using REGEXREPLACE:    

=REGEXREPLACE(A1," the | I | It's | as | a | for | on "," ")
  
The result is:  
  
"Some fog eh Pop I've already heard weather report Drive please Boy as thick pea soup Not soul around miles Know what think pop Perfect place a murder Conversation like television set honeymoon Unnecessary"
    
As you can see it's almost there, but the "a" before the word "murder" still remained, even though the "a" before the word "soul" was correctly removed.     

Scratching head...

Comment: Sorry about my lack of skill formatting the question - thanks player0 for improving it (though I like placing "Google Sheets:" in the title to make it easier to visually parse in SO's search results. 
  
  
  Anyhow, I've created a Google Sheet to work on this. I ended up using a solution by JPV, posted in another related question I had. That solution made use of a range containing words to be excluded. But it has a few problems. See here:
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bkso50ENLAU5ARd5pZ5DkmH-BvMaoM1LAqFsFPlrByg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s\b(the|I|It's|as|a|for|on)\b",)
```

Comment: Yep! There was a minor issue with the word "I", but I seem to have fixed it with this:  
   
`"\s\b(the| I |It's|as|a|for|on)\b"` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, " the |I |It's | as | a | for | on ", " ")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Right, but notice that "pea", "conversation", "television", and "honeymoon" are adverseley affected