# How to find and remove multiple words (as a list) from a cell without using macro

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a string in a cell which is a list of words like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,f,c,a,h
```

I'd like to find and remove all the words which are on this list:

```
c,f,h
```

I can use multiple SUBSTITUTE but since my list is long, nested SUBSTITUTE is not convenient. 
Here is the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ZT3CMJ9vfUcOIvhXYLHUHHQm5tm1Tb1N9hi3LeI0WM/edit#gid=0

There is also [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508994/how-to-remove-multiple-text-strings-from-a-cell) but I'd like to use an existing list instead of manually inserting to the function.

Comment: Sample input and output will be helpful. And replace `c,f,h` to what?

Comment: Please make your sheet public.

Comment: sorry, remove, I meant. I public the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use** an existing list instead of manually inserting to the function.

Make a list of the words you want replaced in a column eg. `A3:A9` and use the following formula to create your expression.

```
=JOIN("|",A3:A9)
```

Then use the working solution from your [mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509575/1527780) (or whichever formula meets your needs) to get the final result.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b("&B3&")\b",)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I question is not very clear. I'd like to remove those words. I will try your solution and update later.

Comment: After having a look at your sheet I have updated the answer because there are no spaces in your text.

Comment: This works. Just a small modification that I use SUBSTITUTE to remove the commas for easier understanding
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A60,A$75,""),",,",",")

Comment: As mentioned _"...or whichever formula meets your needs"_. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a second version based on suggestions from @marikamitsos
, I have added a string ", .. $" to the last partern position because there is no comma at the end of the text in a1.

```
=RegexReplace(RegexReplace(A1&",","\b(" & SUBSTITUTE(A3&",",",",",|") & ")(\b|$)",""),",$","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer, you can also try

```
=textjoin(",", 1, ArrayFormula(regexreplace(split(A2, ","), textjoin("|",1,A5:A8),)))
```